# Asking users for proof of task completion (attestation)

Tags: verification, user-habit

I'm currently working on a project where we are integrating safety tasks around the home into an insurance platform. For a small number of these tasks, we're asking users to provide proof that they have inspected this household item/s by uploading photos of the item/s, then asking a few questions about its condition.

Having done some user testing here, there's a lot of hesitancy from users, namely around the amount of effort/mental load involved, as well as the feeling that they don't feel trusted.

Does anyone know of similar experience in the wild that are done well?

Do they know of methods to ease this process?

Comment: Issues over 'trust' go beyond conventional UX.   You are into behavioural economics / other aspects of psychology - though off the top of my head I can't recall any particular relevant research :-(

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to answer. First of all, why are does photos needed? There might be a good reason that is not clear to the users. So communicate the reason why photos should be uploaded and what the benefit to the user is by doing so.

If there is no good reason...well, listen to the users and do not force them to upload photos they don't want do.